# Create Maven Webapp with NetBeans based on Java EE 8

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I would like to set up a Java EE 8 Application with NetBeans 8.2 and Maven 3.2.2. In my NetBeans Wizard I can only pick Java EE 7. I checked my versions (see screenshots below) and everything seems to be with the JDK 1.8, so there should not be any problems.. Can anyone relate to this issue? I tried to follow [this guide](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/Maven_EE/MavenEE.html#section2s1).

[image: NetBeans JDK Version]

[image: MVN & Java Versions]

Answer (score 1):

It is just an idea but maybe your JEE max version depends on the server you use. 
Else, something is strange, when you ask for the maven version and the java version, it gives you two different version of java .
Hope this might help you :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sadly that did not do the trick. It looks like this depends on the glassfish version, since 4.1 does only support JEE7 (I found this [here](https://jakarta.ee/))